# Configuring ip, subnet and gateway on eth interface

Tags: ethernet, route, ifconfig

I'm in terminal on RedHat 5 and I need to configure one of the two eth interface with different IP, GATEWAY and SUBNET.
I know `ifconfig` and `route add` but I'm not sure what I have to do for configureing the gateway on that particulary eth and, I think, only for that!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

route add default gw 1.2.3.4 eth0

Of course you need to replace 1.2.3.4 with the actual gateway.  This will add the route into the system routing table.